# Tomcat doesn't start automatically in windows

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, server

I installed Tomcat 6.0 in my windows server 2008 R2.I setted
CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21.
When I try to open with startup.bat.Tomcat is running.I can reach the localhost.But I want to get these things with automatically.When I open the start task manager.I cant see any tomcat or apache services.Just I can reach only with command prompt method(you can see the running black screen to below).How to open automatically without entering this parameter.

[image: Picture:Running on black screen]

Edit: Yes,I want to start tomcat with my System starts
Last Edit:I found the main error.Windows doesnt recognize the tomcat.How to define tomcat to windows being a service?

Comment: But I want to get these things with automatically. automatically means what ? Are you want to start tomcat with your System starts ?

Comment: Start automatically? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically run Tomcat when Windows starts, you need to run Tomcat as a service, which is documented here:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html